# Getting Syntax Error while creating AD User for Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

When I am trying to create an Azure Active Directory User, getting syntax error.

`create User s-dbreadwrtnonprod@work.com from external provider;`

Error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins) documentation you need to put the name of the user between brackets.

```
CREATE USER [s-dbreadwrtnonprod@work.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Make sure you have configured Azure Active Directory authentication as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure).

Comment: Thank you Alberto!! I passed that step.

Comment: Now failing with another error.
`Principal 's-dbreadwrtnonprod@work.com' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.`
Tried the solution from [https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmchap/archive/2017/10/08/principal-could-not-be-found-or-this-principal-type-is-not-supported-error-azure-sql-server], but did n't work

Comment: Use this format CREATE USER [your.user_example.com#EXT#@<yourAzureSubscriptionPrefix>.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148325/add-active-directory-user-for-azure-sql-db